# WSL2 Docker Linux Permission Issue with Volumes

Tags: linux, docker, debian, jekyll, wsl-2

I am using Docker to build Jekyll web sites. I am using Windows 10 and WSL2 with Debian.
If I run the following from Powershell in my Windows Environment

```sh
docker run --rm --label=jekyll --volume=C:/_projects/site/theme:/srv/jekyll -it -p 4000:4000 jekyll/jekyll jekyll serve
```

If try and run this from my Debian shell via WSL2

```sh
docker run --rm --label=jekyll --volume=/mnt/c/_projects/site/theme:/srv/jekyll -it -p 4000:4000 jekyll/jekyll jekyll serve
```

Then I get an error:-

```sh
Configuration file: /srv/jekyll/_config.yml
            Source: /srv/jekyll
       Destination: /srv/jekyll/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
jekyll 3.8.5 | Error:  Operation not permitted @ apply2files - /srv/jekyll/_site/assets/css/font-awesome.css
Traceback (most recent call last):
        25: from /usr/local/bundle/bin/jekyll:29:in `<main>'
        24: from /usr/local/bundle/bin/jekyll:29:in `load'
        23: from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
        22: from /usr/gem/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
        21: from /usr/gem/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
        20: from /usr/gem/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
        19: from /usr/gem/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
        18: from /usr/gem/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
        17: from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:75:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
        16: from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `start'
        15: from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `each'
        14: from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `block in start'
        13: from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:36:in `process'
        12: from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:65:in `build'
        11: from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/command.rb:28:in `process_site'
        10: from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/site.rb:73:in `process'
         9: from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/site.rb:208:in `write'
         8: from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/site.rb:330:in `each_site_file'
         7: from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/site.rb:330:in `each'
         6: from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/site.rb:331:in `block in each_site_file'
         5: from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/site.rb:331:in `each'
         4: from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/site.rb:332:in `block (2 levels) in each_site_file'
         3: from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/site.rb:209:in `block in write'
         2: from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/static_file.rb:105:in `write'
         1: from /usr/gem/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/static_file.rb:163:in `copy_file'
/usr/gem/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/static_file.rb:163:in `utime': Operation not permitted @ apply2files - /srv/jekyll/_site/assets/css/font-awesome.css (Errno::EPERM)
```

My instinct is that I am bumping into Linux file permission issue, but I have no idea how to resolve it, or if my hypothesis is correct.

Comment: Run your WSL environment as administrator.

Comment: @RamanSailopal - thanks. Sadly that doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but check out https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly#ensure-volume-mounts-work.  I'm fairly certain the `metadata` option will be required to fix your error.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds - that was the ticket. Thanks so much. If you add it as an answer I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to edit `wsl.conf`

```
sudo nano /etc/wsl.conf

# Now make it look like this and save the file when you're done:
[automount]
root = /
options = "metadata"
```

As outlined in https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly#ensure-volume-mounts-work

Thanks to [@NotTheDr01ds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11810933/notthedr01ds)